# Solve $yy^\prime+x=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $yy^\prime+x=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tried dividing by $y$ to get $$y^\prime+\frac{x}{y}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{y}$$
$$(y^\prime)^2+2\frac{x}{y}+\frac{x^2}{y^2}=\frac{x^2+y^2}{y^2}$$
$$(y^\prime)^2+2\frac{x}{y}=1$$
$$y^\prime=\sqrt{1-2\frac{x}{y}}$$

Tried using $v=\frac{y}{x}$

$$y^\prime=v^\prime x+v$$

$$v^\prime x + v=\sqrt{1-2v^{-1}}$$

Not sure what to do now or if I've even done something right until now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solve the DE $yy^{\prime}+x=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289623/solve-the-de-yy-primex-sqrtx2y2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left side is one half of the derivative of the radikant on the right side. Thus set $u=x^2+y^2$ and you get the standard example
$$
u'=2\sqrt{u},~~u\ge 0.
$$

---

Another approach: Square directly (and remember to later remove the solutions with a negative square root) to get
$$
2xyy'+y^2y'^2=y^2
$$
This is a Clairaut equation for $u=y^2$, as
$$
u=xu'+\frac14u'^2
$$
This as, as per scheme, the family of solution lines
$$
u=cx+\frac14c^2
$$
and the singular solution with $x=-\frac12u'\implies u=-x^2$, which does not give a valid solution for $y$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, then the equation becomes
$$
rr'=r
$$
which means that $r'=1$; that is, $r=x+c$ which is the horizontal parabola
$$
y^2=2cx+c^2
$$

Answer (score 2):

If $f = x^2 + y^2$ then we have $f' = 2\sqrt{f}$. That can be solved easily.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:
$$yy^\prime+x=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$ydy+xdx=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dx$$
$$\frac 12 (dy^2+dx^2)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dx$$
$$\frac 12 \frac {d(x^2+y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=dx$$
Integrate.